# Android studio 3.2, Android SDK Tools 26.0.2 ERROR : Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey guys am having a issue with my android studio
the ERROR is:

`Android resource linking failed
Output:

```
/Users/omar_sameh/Desktop/CarzyOS/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: 'RecyclerView' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: /Users/omar_sameh/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/7761ac785c77afbee7829c87129e0c02/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/omar_sameh/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/omar_sameh/Desktop/CarzyOS/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/omar_sameh/Desktop/CarzyOS/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/omar_sameh/Desktop/CarzyOS/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/omar_sameh/Desktop/CarzyOS/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.omar_sameh.carzyos\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/omar_sameh/Desktop/CarzyOS/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
`
```

**Any suggestions ?**

Comment: open activity_main.xml and check line 9. It seems like you added an incompatible attribute.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache/restart?

Comment: Please paste your `activity_main` code where you used `RecyclerView`.

Comment: i have tried invalidate cache/restart

Answer (score 0):

As per your xml file, the attr element is invalid

```
activity_main.xml:9: error: 'RecyclerView' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference. error: failed linking file resources.
```